# What is the easiest way to integrate iPhone app with Web Sites that don't have web service

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I am about to offer an iphone app for a travel agency. They probably use web services but if not what can I do? What is the easiest way to integrate an iPhone app that read and send data to a website without web service. Site is built with php (I dont know php am a java guy). What can I do for that? Client is a travel agency has a website for ordering hotels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use NSURLConnection to connect to the site and get its HTML.  You just need to have a good parser that can deal with the website and use it like a person would with a browser.

If the site is not cooperating with you, it's not really a good idea. Either, it breaks their Terms of Service or they might just randomly change their site around and your app will break.  Usually this isn't because they are trying to break your app -- they just don't know about it, and they are just trying to keep their site up to date.

If you are cooperating, you don't have to go as far as a SOAP webservice -- or even a complex API.  They just need PHP that dumps out something easy to parse and that is guaranteed not to change.

Comment: You *definitely* want a nice server-side if at all possible.